# Problem with Firebase and DialogFlow. "Initializing firebase-admin may fail"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I am writing the code of a chatbot that creates reservations for a hairdressing salon, they are saved in a database in Firestore.

Everything works well except that after around 20 minutes of inactivity, when the bot functions are executed and the name of the client is consulted in the database, it throws the error in the Google Cloud log:

> ***"Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail"***

Which causes the chatbot to issue an "Empty_Response"

I have read other answers here but the solutions they present have not worked for me. I thought it was a problem with the login statement and package.json, but nothing.

I leave the code below.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

**THIS PART IS EDITED TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION WITH ALL THE CODE AN ADDITIONAL IMAGES**

Before the bot search in the Firestore DB he make a decision depending on the user answer with a number, as show here:

> *Hello, I'm the assistant to the hairdresser! please choose an option:*
>
> *1. Know our address*
> *2. Know our schedules*
> *3. Know our services*
> *4. Make an appointment*

Since you have asked for part of the code, I have updated the question with all the fulfillment so I think it will be easier to help me, in addition to this I have indicated what you have been asking me within the same code:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.7.5",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"
       
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
//Login statement: I've obviously modify login details...

'use strict';
const {dialogflow, SimpleResponse} = require('actions-on-google');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "Here goes my apikey",
    authDomain: "rest***********.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://rest****************-houusi.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "rest*************-houusi",
    storageBucket: "rest***************.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "Here goes my SenderID",
    appId: "Here goes my apiID"
};

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {


//Here is the code for the intent GiveID which is the one that do the search in the DB:
  
function BusquedaHandler(agent){
  const db = admin.firestore();
  
  var id = agent.parameters.identidad;
  var busqueda = db.collection('Clientes').doc(id);
  
         return busqueda.get().then( snap => {
         
                if (snap.exists) {
                 
                  const alldata = snap.data();
                  const nombre = alldata.Nombre;
                  
                  agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`); 
                  agent.setFollowupEvent({ 'name': 'conid', 'parameters': {'nombre': nombre, 'identidad': id,}});
                  return console.log("LECTURA DE LA BASE DE DATOS!");
                  
                } else {
                  
                  agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`);
                  agent.setFollowupEvent({ 'name': 'noid', 'parameters': {'identidad': id,}});     
                  return console.log("NO ENCONTRADO EN BASE DE DATOS!");     
                }
          });
    
              
} 
  
//End to the code for the intent GiveID

//****************************************************************
  
 //This is the code to write in the DB with an ID

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function GuardarHandler(agent){
    
    const db = admin.firestore();
    let id = agent.parameters.identidad;
    let name = agent.parameters.nombre;
    let date = agent.parameters.date;
    let Servicio = agent.parameters.servicio;
    let Trabajador = agent.parameters.trabajador;
    let time = agent.parameters.hora;
     
     db.collection('Reservas').add({ 
          Cif: id,
          FechaReserva: date,
          Hora: time,
          NombreCte: name,
          Observaciones: Servicio + ', ATENDIDO POR: ' + Trabajador,
          Telefono: '',
          });
         
        agent.add('Perfecto ' + name + ' su cita fue apuntada!, en unos minutos nos contactaremos con usted para confirmarla.');
    
        return console.log("CON ID GUARDADO EN LA BASE DE DATOS!");  
  }
//End to write Db with ID
  
//*************************************************************************
  
//Code to write in DB with No ID
  
  function GuardarNoIdHandler(agent){
    
    const db = admin.firestore();
    let id = agent.parameters.identidad;
    let name = agent.parameters.nombre;
    var dateobj = new Date();
    var date = dateobj.toISOString(); 
    var time = date;
    let obser = agent.parameters.servicio;
    let tel = agent.parameters.telefono;

        db.collection('Reservas').add({ 
          Cif: id,
          FechaReserva: date,
          Hora: time,
          NombreCte: name,
          Observaciones: 'CLIENTE NO REGISTRADO: ' + obser,
          Telefono: tel,
          });
         
        agent.add('Muchas Gracias ' + name + '! le contactaremos para organizar su cita con más detalle.');
   
    return console.log("NO ID GUARDADO EN LA BASE DE DATOS!");
  }
 //End to Write in DB with No ID 
  
  //********************************************************************
 
 //If the user select the number 4 in 
//the question then the bot redirect the 
//event *askid* following this code:
  
 function DecisionHandler(agent){
   let decision = agent.parameters.decision;


   if (decision == 'direccion') {agent.add('HERE GOES THE ADRESS');}
   if (decision == 'horarios') {agent.add('HERE GOES THE SCHEDULES');}
   if (decision == 'servicios') {agent.add('HERE GOES THE SERVICES');}

   if (decision == 'cita') {
     agent.add(' ');
     agent.setFollowupEvent({ 'name': 'askid',});
    }
   return console.log("DECISION TOMADA!... REDIRECCIONANDO INTENCION");


 }
  
//end for the code in the welcome intent 
//And just here is where the empty_response 
//message is shown, and the error in the 
//log of GCLOUD_PROJECT too.
  
//***********************************************************************
  
//In this one the bot search for the type 
//of services if is another it activate 
//another intent call OtrosServicios
  
  function AnalizarReservaHandler(agent){
  
    let id = agent.parameters.identidad;
    let name = agent.parameters.nombre;
    let date = agent.parameters.date;
    let Trabajador = agent.parameters.trabajador;
    let time = agent.parameters.hora;
    let otros = agent.parameters.otros;
    
    let servicio = agent.parameters.servicio;
    
    if (servicio === 'Otro'){
      
      let servicio = agent.parameters.otros;
      agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`);
      agent.setFollowupEvent({ 
      'name': 'otroserv', 
      'parameters': {
        'nombre': name, 
        'identidad': id,
        'date' : date,
        'servicio' : servicio,
        'trabajador' : Trabajador,
        'hora' : time,
         }
       
        }); 
      return console.log("SERVICIO = OTRO");
      
       }else{
     
     agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`);
     agent.setFollowupEvent({ 
      'name': 'guardar', 
      'parameters': {
        'nombre': name, 
        'identidad': id,
        'date' : date,
        'servicio' : servicio,
        'trabajador' : Trabajador,
        'hora' : time,
         }
        }); 
         return console.log('SERVICIO NORMAL');
    }
  
  }

//End to search for services
  
//***********************************************************************
  
//This is the same as above but with NoID appointment
  
  function AnalizarReservaNOIDHandler(agent){
  
    let id = agent.parameters.identidad;
    let date = agent.parameters.date;
    let Trabajador = agent.parameters.trabajador;
    let time = agent.parameters.hora;
    let telefono = agent.parameters.telefono;
    let otros = agent.parameters.otros;
    let servicio = agent.parameters.servicio;
    
    let name = agent.parameters.nombre.name;
    
    
    if (servicio === 'Otro'){
      
      let servicio = agent.parameters.otros;
      agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`);
      agent.setFollowupEvent({ 
      'name': 'otroservNOID', 
      'parameters': {
        'nombre': name, 
        'identidad': id,
        'date' : date,
        'servicio' : servicio,
        'trabajador' : Trabajador,
        'hora' : time,
        'telefono' : telefono,
         }
       
        }); 
      return console.log("SERVICIO = OTRO");
      
       }else{
     
     agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`);
     agent.setFollowupEvent({ 
      'name': 'guardarnoid', 
      'parameters': {
        'nombre': name, 
        'identidad': id,
        'date' : date,
        'servicio' : servicio,
        'trabajador' : Trabajador,
        'hora' : time,
        'telefono' : telefono,

         }
        }); 
         return console.log('SERVICIO NORMAL');
    }
  
  }
//End to other services without ID
  
//*****************************************************************
  
//This One is to save the input for 
//the client for other type of services that was not listed
  
  function otroservicioHandler(agent){
    let id = agent.parameters.identidad;
    let name = agent.parameters.nombre;
    let date = agent.parameters.date;
   
    let Trabajador = agent.parameters.trabajador;
    let time = agent.parameters.hora;
    let servicio = agent.parameters.otros;
    
    agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`);
    agent.setFollowupEvent({ 
      'name': 'guardar', 
      'parameters': {
        'nombre': name, 
        'identidad': id,
        'date' : date,
        'servicio' : servicio,
        'trabajador' : Trabajador,
        'hora' : time,
         }
        }); 
    return console.log('OTRO SERVICIO REGISTRADO');
  }
 
//End for other service
    
//**************************
  
//the same as above but without ID
  
  function otroservicioNOIDHandler(agent){
    let id = agent.parameters.identidad;
    let name = agent.parameters.nombre;
    let date = agent.parameters.date;
    let telefono = agent.parameters.telefono;
   
    let Trabajador = agent.parameters.trabajador;
    let time = agent.parameters.hora;
    let servicio = agent.parameters.otros;

    agent.add(`Procesando solicitud`);
    agent.setFollowupEvent({ 
      'name': 'guardarnoid', 
      'parameters': {
        'nombre': name, 
        'identidad': id,
        'date' : date,
        'servicio' : servicio,
        'trabajador' : Trabajador,
        'hora' : time,
        'telefono' : telefono,

         }
        }); 
    return console.log('OTRO SERVICIO REGISTRADO');
  }
 
//end for othr service without id

//************************************

//This is the declaration of intents
 
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Guardar_Reserva', GuardarHandler);
  intentMap.set('reserva_NoId', AnalizarReservaNOIDHandler);
  intentMap.set('Give_id', BusquedaHandler);
  intentMap.set('welcome_decision', DecisionHandler);
  intentMap.set('direccion', DecisionHandler);
  intentMap.set('horario', DecisionHandler);
  intentMap.set('servicios', DecisionHandler);
  intentMap.set('hacer_cita', DecisionHandler);
  intentMap.set('reserva', AnalizarReservaHandler);
  intentMap.set('Otros_servicios', otroservicioHandler);
  intentMap.set('Otros_servicios_NOID', otroservicioNOIDHandler);
  intentMap.set('Guardar_Reserva_NOID', GuardarNoIdHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

The message problem show to the user:
[image: The message problem show to the user]

The alert show in GCloud:
[image: The alert show in GCloud]

This is the new image with the intent Welcome where I ask for the number 4 an so on:
[image: This is the new image with the intent Welcome where I ask for the number 4 an so on]

And this One is the Intent where the bot ask for an ID:
[image: And this One is the Intent where the bot ask for an ID]

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code for the Intent Handler where you're trying to make the call to firestore? If there are other error messages in the logs, these may be helpful as well, along with any information about where this code is running (is this using the Dialogflow Inline Editor? Are you running it using Firebase Cloud Functions? Someplace else? The warning you're seeing is unlikely to be the cause of your problems, but we require additional information to help - the more info you can provide, the better chances we have of helping you figure it out!

Comment: Ok, I'm using inline editor and i will edit the question! Thanks!

Comment: This provides some insight, but additional information would help. Can you update your question with a screen shot of the Intent in Dialogflow that should be accepting when they enter "4" (and other numbers, for that matter) and a screen shot of the Intent that handles the "askid" event? It would also help to see the code that you're using to call `DecisionHandler()`.

Comment: Ok, ill do it, but there is no code to call DecisionHandler, cuz this is the welcome intent

Comment: Where do you register `DecisionHandler()` as the Intent Handler for the welcome intent? Can you update your question to include the code for the Intent Handler for the "Give_id" Intent?